# I am solving a system of ODEs by using Xcos in Scilab 6.1.1, but the user-defined function gives me anerrors

Tags: scilab

[I am solving a system of ODEs by using Xcos (SIRD infection model) in Scilab 6.1.1 version and I am using Windows 10 operating system, but the user-defined function gives me errors.

Initial conditions: S(0)=10^7-1000; I(0)=1000; R(0)=0; D(0)=0.
I tried to use 1/S block, but it does not accept vector initial conditions, so I used integrator block and I am not sure if is it correct or not. Please, I need your help to figure out this error. I am going to attach a screenshot of the Xcos file of the SIRD model simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Xcos to do such a simulation. Use directly the ode() solver, like in the following example (replace parameters with your values)

```
function dxdt=f(t,x)
    S=x(1);
    I=x(2);
    R=x(3);
    D=x(4);
    dxdt=[-β*S*I/N
           β*S*I/N-γ*I-μ*I
           γ*I
           μ*I]
end

N = 1000;
β = 0.4;
γ = 0.035;
μ = 0.0035;

t=linspace(0,100,1000);
x0=[997; 3; 0; 0]
x=ode(x0,0,t,f);

clf
plot(t,x)
legend S I R D
```

[image]